# why does ++i not increment i before for loop?

Tags: javascript, syntax

So the following two functions print out the same exact results.

```
console.log("i++");
 for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
  console.log(i); // 1, 2
}
console.log("++i");
for (i=1; i<=3; ++i) {
  console.log(i); // 1, 2
}
```

This very counter intuitive as I'm specifically asking to post-increment one and per-increment the other. 
It would be very desirable behavior to increment the value before the run inside the for loop. Is this behavior consistent?, Is this javascript specific or is this the standard behavior across programming languages that use ++i, i++ syntax and for loops?

Comment: *"It would be very desirable behavior to increment the value before the run inside the for loop."* You can accomplish that as well. There's no reason that the 3rd segment of the `for` statement's head must contain the increment. `for (i=1; ++i<=3; ) {`

Comment: Or if you wanted the `i` evaluated as is, but then incremented before the body, then change it to post increment `for (i=1; i++<=3; ) {`

Comment: squint, I did not think of this THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome. Just be aware that these days such uses of pre/post increment/decrement operator are often frowned upon. Some new languages are excluding those operations altogether. You may be better off just doing `i < 3` and then putting the `i++` at the top of the body. Slightly more verbose, but arguably clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The third expression in the `for` loop header is evaluated **after** each iteration. Thus:

1. `i` is initialized to `1`
2. The loop test expression, `i <= 3`, is evaluated (and found to be `true`)
3. The loop body is executed
4. `i++` or `++i` happens

Except for the minor syntax differences, that's exactly what would have happened in a C program in 1976.